# JTable does not accept text from Windows IME keyboard directly

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to hit F2 to start editing the cell before input the IME text. Is there any solution on it?

Comment: You can use a [different binding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11668294/230513).

Comment: I have already tried the key bindings but unfortunately the IME keyboard does not trigger any key event in Java.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: I think the post explains the situation

[http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4708736](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4708736)